# Mazda MPV 2005 only fits 500ml of window washer fluid

Tags: mazda, window

I have a Japanese manufacturer Mazda MPV 2005 and had the washing fluid tank completely empty, ie. it was not spraying anymore.

I filled this up with a mix of window washer fluid and water, but to my surprise it was full after ca 500ml of liquid. This seems awfully little.

I'm sure I filled the right spot, I double checked with a range of web resources.

Can someone confirm this is the correct amount or if not what to check to fill this properly?

Window washers do work now, however the mix is way too "soapy" now, as I expected to have at least 2 litre space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick eBay search [appears to indicate](http://www.ebay.com/itm/00-01-02-03-04-05-06-MAZDA-MPV-WINDSHIELD-WASHER-BOTTLE-RESERVOIR-W-PUMP-OEM-/351407441662?fits=Make%3AMazda%7CModel%3AMPV&hash=item51d18406fe&vxp=mtr) that the washer reservoir's capacity is rather limited:

[image: eBay picture]